# Retrieving history of a message within Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Graph Explorer to look at my Team's channel's message data, I've noticed an etag property and am wondering what that property is used for.

The reason I ask is that this property changes when a message has been edited and am hoping that it could link me to the pre-edited message from the current message. Note that it's possible that Microsoft doesn't store the original message.

here's a tiny snippet of the property in question when querying, https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group-id-for-teams}/channels/{channel-id}/messages/{message-id}

```
{
    "@odata.context": "<redacted>",
    "id": "157540775----",
    "replyToId": null,
    "etag": "15754980----",
    "messageType": "message",
    "createdDateTime": "2019-12-03T21:15:58.713Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-12-04T22:21:28.967Z",
    "deletedDateTime": null,
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it possible that this is related to the [HTTP ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag)?

Comment: yeah.. seems like i'm chasing something that doesn't exist :\

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Teams does not store the history of a chat message. You can only tell if the message has been modified if the `lastEditedDateTime` property is null or not.

The `etag` property is the version number of the chat message according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta#properties). I suppose how this can be used is in an application that stores chat messages and will need to know if the message information they have stored is stale and needs to be updated.

Comment: Teams does store the message history. You can retrieve the message history when exporting to PST with Purview. Unfortunately, it appears that the Graph API does not provide access to the history.